# imread() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flatten'

Tags: python

The following code shows error. Kindly help to resolve this issue.

```py
    filepath = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train', img_name)
    img = imread(filepath, flatten=True)
```

error pic:

[image: TypeError]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`imread()` from scipy is deprecated and they recommend the use of `imageio.imread()`. A guide to transitioning to the `imageio` version can be found [here](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scipy.html).  According to that, your code should change to:

```
import imageio

filepath = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train', img_name)
img = imageio.imread(filepath, as_gray=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from scipy import ndimage
filepath = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train', img_name)
img = ndimage.imread(filepath, flatten=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using matplotlib.pyplot's imread instead of scipy.ndimage.imread, which should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `imread()` does not have keyword argument `flatten`

for example:

```
In [3]: def poi(a, b):
   ...:     print a
   ...:     

In [4]: poi(c=12)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b07b2111af2e> in <module>()
----> 1 poi(c=12)

TypeError: poi() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
```

You need to check the function's argument for what it accepts .